# How to open parquet files in a gzip format in a zip archive as a pandas dataframe in python without first extracting it?

Tags: python, pandas, zip, gzip, parquet

I have a series of zip files containing parquet files that are in a gzip format. I am trying to open the parquet files in pandas without extracting the whole archive first. From the python zipfile libraries I can get this code to work to open csv files

```
from pandas import read_csv as pdread_csv
from glob import glob as gglob
from os import path as ospath
from zipfile import ZipFile as zfZipFile

data = r'C:\...\TestZipFolder\*.zip'

for mzip in gglob(data):
    with zfZipFile(mzip) as czip:
        for file in zfZipFile(mzip).namelist():
            with czip.open(file) as cfile:
                cfiledf = pdread_csv(cfile)
                print(cfile_df)
```

This prints out a `DataFrame` that matches a csv file in the zip file.
I tried to extend this logic to opening a parquet file and modified the code to;

```
from pandas import read_csv as pdread_csv, read_parquet as pdread_parquet
from glob import glob as gglob
from os import path as ospath
from zipfile import ZipFile as zfZipFile

data = r'C:\...\ParquetZipFolder\*.zip'

for mzip in gglob(data):
    with zfZipFile(mzip) as czip:
        for file in zfZipFile(mzip).namelist():
            with czip.open(file) as cfile:
                cfiledf = pdread_parquet(cfile)
                print(cfile_df)
```

This returns `NotImplementedError`: That compression method is not supported
Looking at python resources for gzip it suggested opening the gzip with `open()` as a binary object so I modified the code with;

```
    for mzip in gglob(data):
    with zfZipFile(mzip) as czip:
        for file in zfZipFile(mzip).namelist():
            with czip.open(open(file)) as cfile:
                cfiledf = pdread_parquet(cfile)
                print(cfile_df)
```

No such file or directory: 'C:\...\ParquetZipFolder\Parquet1.zip\parquetfile.parquet.gzip'

So I imported gzip and tried gzip

```
for mzip in gglob(data):
    with zfZipFile(mzip) as czip:
        for file in zfZipFile(mzip).namelist():
            with gzip.open(ospath.join(mzip,file), mode='rb', compresslevel=9, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None) as cfile:
                cfile_df = pdread_parquet(cfile)
                print(cfile_df)
```

and...

```
for mzip in gglob(data):
    with zfZipFile(mzip) as czip:
        for file in zfZipFile(mzip).namelist():
            with gzip.open(file, mode='rb', compresslevel=9, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None) as cfile:
                cfile_df = pdread_parquet(cfile)
                print(cfile_df)
```

and...

```
for mzip in gglob(data):
    with zfZipFile(mzip) as czip:
        for file in zfZipFile(mzip).namelist():
            with czip.open(gzip.open(file, mode='rb', compresslevel=9, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None)) as cfile:
                cfile_df = pdread_parquet(cfile)
                print(cfile_df)
```

Each either returns the not file found or compression method is not supported.
Not sure how to get zipfile to either ignore the compression and pass it along to gzip or open as a binary and just pass it along to pandas.

Comment: why are you zipping your parquet files? parquet has compression built-in

Comment: Are the parquet zips password protected?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are gzipping the parquet files then adding the to a zip file.

Comment: This isn't something I did personally, but how I received the data. There is over 20Gb of data in the 3 zip files I have and they are structured like so. Parquet2019.zip contains 12 fles for example JAN.parquet.gzip. There are zip files for 2019, 2020, 2021 and each has a file for each month.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this replicates what you have:

- one or more .parquet file(s)
- each file is the individually gzipped (.parquet.gz)
- gzipped file(s) zipped together (.parquet.gz.zip)

Then you can leverage `io.BytesIO()` to open the inner archive passing that to pandas.

This example uses data from:

https://github.com/apache/parquet-testing/blob/master/data/delta_byte_array.parquet

and a single parquet file but should work with zip archives with multiple files.

```py
import contextlib
import gzip
import io
import zipfile

import pandas

## -----------------
## Process a single file as glob is not part of the problem here
## source: https://github.com/apache/parquet-testing/blob/master/data/delta_byte_array.parquet
## -----------------
zip_file_path = "foo/delta_byte_array.parquet.gz.zip"
## -----------------

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path) as zip_file:
    for child_zip_file_path in zip_file.namelist():
        ## -----------------
        ## use an ExitStack to simplify things
        ## -----------------
        with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
            unzipped_child = stack.enter_context(zip_file.open(child_zip_file_path))
            unzipped_child_bytes = stack.enter_context(io.BytesIO(unzipped_child.read()))
            ungzipped_child = stack.enter_context(gzip.open(unzipped_child_bytes))
            df = pandas.read_parquet(ungzipped_child)
        ## -----------------
        print(df)
```

That will give you something like:

```
[1000 rows x 9 columns]
        c_customer_id c_salutation  ...                   c_email_address c_last_review_date
0    AAAAAAAAIODAAAAA          Sir  ...    Mark.Bailey@rg9qCNVJ0s7qeY.com            2452443
1    AAAAAAAAHODAAAAA         Mrs.  ...         Lisa.Clark@goPYS4tMB0.org            2452646
2    AAAAAAAAGODAAAAA          Ms.  ...       Evelyn.Joyner@ialYx1zLN.edu            2452439
3    AAAAAAAAFODAAAAA          Sir  ...  Harvey.Stanford@sl59JiHqrp8X.org            2452632
4    AAAAAAAAEODAAAAA          Dr.  ...             Chris.Davis@k6S3Q.com            2452570
..                ...          ...  ...                               ...                ...
995  AAAAAAAAFAAAAAAA          Sir  ...               Robert.Moran@Hh.edu            2452469
996  AAAAAAAAEAAAAAAA          Dr.  ...               Michael.White@i.org            2452361
997  AAAAAAAADAAAAAAA         Miss  ...            Latisha.Hamilton@V.com            2452313
998  AAAAAAAACAAAAAAA          Dr.  ...            Amy.Moses@Ovk9KjHH.com            2452318
999  AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA          Mr.  ...      Javier.Lewis@VFAxlnZEvOx.org            2452508

[1000 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: This gives me the same NotImplementedError: That compression method is not supported. My zipfiles are Parquet2019.zip and contain files JAN.parquet.gzip and there are 12 for each zip folder and a zip folder for each year in that scheme. Which I think is the same as what you describe excepts my gzip files have a .gzip extension and not .gz; could that be the issue?

Comment: For what it is worth, my parquet supports comes via pyarrow.

Comment: I have pyarrow to; when I extract them it works by just feeding the .gzip to pandas read_parquet. When I try with it in a zip it get the same 2 errors; file not found or compression not recognized. Even when I try to pass it to pyarrow

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `gzip.GzipFile` instead of `zipfile.ZipFile`

Comment: @0x26res Potentially, I though I was using the same set of libraries as the original post but looking back it is unclear which package they are using for zip name resolution